# Node, Mongoose connection to IBM Bluemix Compose for Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud, compose-db

How do you use Mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose ?

The example here: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/compose-mongodb-helloworld-nodejs worked great.
Here is a simplified snippet of the example mongo code:

```
MongoClient.connect(credentials.uri, { // step 1: connect
    mongos: {...},
    function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            mongodb = db.db("examples"); // step 2: create or use database
        }
    }
);
```

I can not find a mongoose example that uses a two step connection process.

I noticed that Compose for Mongodb does not support a direct connect to the existing examples database.
Connecting to this url:

```
mongodb://admin:PW@bluemix...4.dblayer.com:22601,bluemix...0.dblayer.com:22601/examples'
```

results in 'MongoError: authentication fail'

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from a sample that was using Compose for MongoDB and Mongoose:

```
var mongoDbUrl, mongoDbOptions = {};
var mongoDbCredentials = appEnv.getServiceCreds("mycomposedb").credentials;
var ca = [new Buffer(mongoDbCredentials.ca_certificate_base64, 'base64')];
mongoDbUrl = mongoDbCredentials.uri;
mongoDbOptions = {
  mongos: {
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: ca,
    poolSize: 1,
    reconnectTries: 1
  }
};
console.log("Connecting to", mongoDbUrl);
mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, mongoDbOptions); // connect to our database
```

Then you can switch database with [useDb](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#drivers_node-mongodb-native_connection_NativeConnection-useDb).

[The full source code is here](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/insurance-bot/blob/949003a89bda41decb4416fe45e3362c587a0dbc/app.js)

Answer (score 1):

Neither Frederic's code snippet (uses Mongo driver), nor the source code he linked (connects to admin db) enable one to use **mongoose** to connect to a custom MongoDB.

In order to connect to a custom db with **mongoose** IBM Compose, you must provide a different connection string than the default provided by Compose.

The following connection string template works:

```
var connectionUrl = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>,<hostname-n>:<port-n>/<db-name>?ssl=true&authSource=admin';
```

with the following options:

```
var sslCA = [fs.readFileSync('mongo.cert')];
var options = {
  ssl: true,
  sslValidate: true,
  sslCA,
};
```

I've provided [the complete working example](https://github.com/cdimascio/mongoose-compose-example) on [Github](https://github.com/cdimascio/mongoose-compose-example)